# Can't start Sitecore website

Tags: .net, xml, sitecore

I'm trying to set up Sitecore website and I get the error bellow. I'm new to .net and have no idea what to do. Looked all config files I could find, but didn't find any weird characters. I created website with SIM tool and followed Sitecore steps. Thank you for help.

```
[XmlException: Root element is missing.]
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +88
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() +1611
   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace) +185
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) +134
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename) +146
   Sitecore.Xml.XmlUtil.LoadXmlFile(String filename) +144
   ..() +19
   ...ctor(String fileName) +432
   Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.NexusLicenseApi.() +284
   Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.NexusLicenseApi.GetModuleCount(String name) +138
   Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.NexusLicenseApi.HasModule(String name) +131
   Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.XdbSettings.get_HasValidLicense() +22
   Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.XdbSettings.get_Enabled() +9
   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.Initialize.ShowXdbInfo.Process(PipelineArgs args) +216
   (Object , Object[] ) +71
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +479
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +255
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +673
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +583
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +169
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +396
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +333

[HttpException (0x80004005): Root element is missing.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +124
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +700
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have valid Sitecore license?

Comment: The license file is empty. I followed their steps and had to choose license location, but it created empty file.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot start Sitecore site without a valid Sitecore `license.xml` file. It's not enough to create an empty `license.xml` file.

If you work for Sitecore partner, ask you employer to give you access to the partner license file.

If you work for Sitecore client, you should have access to the client's license.

From what I know, there is no other way to obtain a valid license (well, maybe time-limited demo license from Sitecore directly).